# Open / Closed Principle

Tags: c#, interfaces, solid, open-close

I found [this code example explaining Open / Closed principle](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/OCP.aspx).

Code before application of principle:

```
public class Logger
{
    public void Log(string message, LogType logType)
    {
        switch (logType)
        {
            case LogType.Console:
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                break;

            case LogType.File:
                // Code to send message to printer
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum LogType
{
    Console,
    File
}
```

And refactored code:

```
public class Logger
{
    IMessageLogger _messageLogger;

    public Logger(IMessageLogger messageLogger)
    {
        _messageLogger = messageLogger;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        _messageLogger.Log(message);
    }
}

public interface IMessageLogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}    

public class ConsoleLogger : IMessageLogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class PrinterLogger : IMessageLogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        // Code to send message to printer
    }
}
```

Can you explain me the reason to still keep `Logger` class with private `IMessageLogger` instance? I would simply avoid it by:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}    

public class PrinterLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        // Code to send message to printer
    }
}
```

The only reason I can think about is, that in suggested solution with `Logger` class, we could still refer to this class in client code, but we still need to modify all `Log(msg)` calls to remove `LogType` arguments.

Comment: This feels to me like an example that was oversimplified just a bit too much, and now doesn't make any sense in practice (i.e., yes you're right). The `Logger(IMessageLogger)` form would make sense iff the `Logger` class contained some meaningful logic of its own other than blind passthroughs to the `IMessageLogger`. For instance, a `Logger` that prepends timestamps to every message or tries to prevent logging the same message too many times might be useful. But I've always been a bit fuzzy on how the O/C principle is supposed to work...

Comment: Ok this does make sense. Maybe something like `// Some additional logic` comment inside `Logger` class would make it more clear.

Comment: This isn't an example of the Open / Closed principle. It's an exercise in converting a switch statement into one based on subtype polymorphism.

Comment: In the _"before refactoring"_ the client code hints at the kind of logging it wants (via the `LogType` parameter). In _"after refactoring"_ this is reversed in that the the client is **given** a specific kind of logging. I think that this reversal makes for an odd example.

Comment: @DavidSoroko: I don't follow you. In refactored code, client still hints the logging implementation by creation of proper `IMessageLogger` in the first case or `ILogger` in the second case.

Comment: I guess that this case the refactoring makes no sense as the purpose of the original `Logger` (abstract the actual implementation from the client) is completely gone. I was thinking of an alternative where logic outside of a client, creates and hands an instance of a `Logger` to the client. This retains the original flavor of the code.

Comment: @DavidArno: it is both, an OCP example *and* what you wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the new `Logger` class does not contain more code, the example seems to be contrived. But imagine that class gets some more methods, with code which is independent from the concrete `IMessageLogger`, for example:

```
public class Logger
{
    // ...
    public void LogFormatted(string formatString, string[] parameters )
    {
        string message = string.Format(formatString, parameters);
        _messageLogger.Log(message);
    }
}
```

Then it makes sense to have a class where you can implement this additional code in 
one place, keeping the program DRY.

The pattern we see here is the classic "strategy" pattern. This becomes obvious when you rename `IMessageLogger` to `ILoggingStrategy`, and the derived classes to `ConsoleLoggingStrategy` and `PrinterLoggingStrategy`.

It is also a demonstration of the OCP, because now you can put `Logger` and `IMessageLogger` (or `ILoggingStrategy`) into a reusable library (or framework), whilst new `IMessageLogger` derivations can reside in application code using that lib. So the lib, including the `Logger`class, won't have to be changed if someone wants to add something like a new strategy like `CloudLoggingStrategy`, for example. In the original code, however, a lib containing the `Logger` class would have to be changed for such an extension.

Comment: Great complex answer! I really like your explanation of OCP together with "strategy" pattern here.